# Que signifie « Attitude légère mais pas aérienne » ?

Tags: sens, expressions

J'ai lu dans un texte ce passage : « ma mère me renvoyait l’image que je me faisais de moi-même. Elle était moins cet autre situé à l’extérieur de moi. Elle était mon altérité. Quant aux autres, ils resteront pour moi des autres. Attitude légère mais pas aérienne ». Que signifie « Attitude légère mais pas aérienne » ?

Answer (score 1):

Voici une liste de quelques mots ou expression pouvant potentiellement aider à la compréhension de cette phrase:

- Cœur **léger**: Conscience apaisée. [Source](http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/7418/c-ur-leger/)
- **Attitude**: Comportement affecté par quelqu'un qui veut cacher ses sentiments réels [Source](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/attitude/6295)
- Appui **aérien**: Un appui aérien consiste dans le langage militaire à apporter un soutien par le biais des airs aux forces terrestres ou maritimes. [Source](http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/15047/appui-aerien/)

---

On peut donc interpréter la phrase

> « **Attitude légère** mais pas **aérienne** »

de plusieurs manières, il nous faudrait plus de contexte pour trouver la bonne, je vais cependant me permettre de faire quelques suggestions en tentant de **paraphraser** avec le contexte existant:

> « Elle resta sereine, tout en gardant la tête sur les épaules. »
>   « Elle se senti donc détendue, mais quelque chose la tracassant tout de même. »
>   « Elle cacha donc ses sentiments sans pour autant devenir irrationnelle. »
>   « Elle était donc désormais en paix. »

Answer (score 0):

Cela signifie, il me semble, que c'est une attitude qui n'est pas définissable par des caractéristiques fortement marquées, par exemple l'attitude de quelqu'un qui montre un intérêt non négligeable  mais qui n'est passionné vraiment par rien (légère), cependant une attitude qui n'est pas insaisissable, une attitude dont l'existence a des manifestations observables (non aérienne).